Would it be possible to create a relatively permanent Kessler syndrome event in interplanetary space between Earth and Venus?
A lot of interplanetary space infrastructure would be focused around Lagrange points, where collision energies would be very low. The threat in this case would come from everything traveling between planets and these regions. These spacecraft would be on a variety of different orbits optimizing for desired time and ∆v costs, and would generally be bound to stop at a planet or some structure. Others would be cyclers, which would be on orbits that allow them to travel quickly through the space between Earth and Venus, but would also take them much further beyond the planets orbits. There would also of course be plenty of stuff in orbit around the planets themselves, but that wouldn't affect interplanetary space.
This is, I think, distinct from a Dyson sphere/swarm situation. That would (generally) be closer to the sun and in more circular orbits, and therefore would also behave more like the traditional LEO collisional cascade (Kessler event? Is there a preferred term for this?).
In this case, even if a collisional cascade began at some point when the planets are relatively close to one another and the space between them is most densely packed, the debris would rapidly dissipate to a huge variety of barely-intersecting orbits around the Sun. The orbits do still intersect though, so the instability would slowly grow.
So my question is a little multifaceted - Could the interplanetary traffic become dense enough or interact enough with densely-populated lagrange regions to initiate a collisional cascade? How long would it take to go from just a slight increase in the background meteoroid threat to something that could shut down interplanetary travel long-term?

The thing about space is there is a lot of it. Hard to imagine how we could throw up enough hardware to Kessler-ize the solar system.

Can I clarify, are you thinking "general ring of debris", or "debris drifting near really useful points only"?

I was thinking more along the lines of "debris near useful points and interrupting traffic" but wasn't sure if that would be possible without a whole ring of debris, because of how much space there is

The reason it's possible to get a dangerous amount of debris in LEO is that the orbital period is only an hour or so, so you re-encounter the same piece of debris again and again and again. A cycler orbit between Earth and Venus might take months to complete; that's a long time between encounters.

Didn't someone do exactly this a couple of billion years ago? Between Mars and Jupiter that is. Although it was about 1% of a planet's worth of material it didn't block any of our traffic so far.
